# Compare non-boxed value type byte-by-byte

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, unsafe

Is there a method in .NET (possibly internal) which can compare any two values of the same type for equality, without doing any boxing at all, and byte-by-byte? I know there is `ValueType.Equals`, which checks if there aren't any references contained in the value type (calling in turn `ValueType.FastEqualsCheck`) and compares them byte-by-byte, but you have to box the value in order to call this method.

I know I can implement this method reflection-wise via `FieldInfo.GetValueDirect`, but it still would be a bit slow due to the reflection.

The method should be generic or accept `TypedReference` (as most similar internal methods do).

Edit: An unsafe method doing the comparison manually:

```
public static class ByteComparer<T> where T : struct
{
    public static readonly Func<T, T, bool> Compare;

    static ByteComparer()
    {
        var t = typeof(T);

        var dyn = new DynamicMethod("Compare", typeof(bool), new[]{t, t}, typeof(ByteComparer<T>));
        var il = dyn.GetILGenerator();

        il.DeclareLocal(t.MakeByRefType(), true);
        il.DeclareLocal(t.MakeByRefType(), true);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, 0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, 1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, t);

        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(ByteComparer<T>).GetMethod("ByteCompare", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static), null);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Compare = (Func<T,T,bool>)dyn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T,T,bool>));
    }

    private static unsafe bool ByteCompare(byte* a, byte* b, int size)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(*(a+i) != *(b+i)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not really any good reason to avoid boxing as a goal in and of itself. If you have a specific scenario in mind where boxing is a problem, you need to provide a good [mcve] showing that scenario and explaining precisely what the problem is. As far as some method existing, boxing is handled at the compiler level; you can override `Equals()` for specific types or implement `IEquatable<T>`, but any general-purpose method is likely going to involve boxing at some point. Have you tried writing an `unsafe` generic method yourself for the task? What _have_ you tried?

Comment: @PeterDuniho As I said, I was just wondering if .NET already provided such a method. I am concerned about boxing due to its mild speed issues, and also out of curiosity. I know I can override Equals and implement IEquatable (and I know this is superior to any other way), but I am looking for a general method working for any value. `unsafe` methods really don't work with generics, and there is no unsafe byte comparison if I remember.

Comment: Given `byte*` pointers, you can write your memcmp yourself. `unsafe` works poorly with _any_ managed type, but fact is you're going to run into issues regardless. You can emit IL (like in your example), or e.g. `AllocHGlobal()` (i.e. an unmanaged block of memory) to copy your managed struct into memory where you can get a pointer and compare, and that works as well in a generic method as anywhere else. But: what's the _solvable programming problem_ here? You can look in the docs as well as anyone else, so just asking if a method exists doesn't seem useful. What's the _real_ question?